# React asynchronous call throws Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.getOwnPropertyNames

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I am trying to call a weather api to fetch the data asynchronously.
I am using react with redux.
I know that the state of the object is initially undefined, and after a success from the API return, the same will be populated again. But when i am trying to check for the object to be undefined or null, it always throws error.

Defining the action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchWeather(location){
   return function(dispatch){
       axios.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/2f986c7548abb959/conditions/q/'+ location.state + "/" + location.city + ".json")
       .then((response) => {
           dispatch({
               type: "FETCH_WEATHER_FULLFILLED", 
               weather: response.data 
           })
       }).catch( (err) => {
           dispatch({
               type: "FETCH_WEATHER_REJECTED", 
               payload: err 
           })
       })
   } 
}
```

The component/App.js,

```
import React from 'react';

import Weather from './Weather';
import LocationForm from './LocationForm';

import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/weatherActions';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';

@connect( (store) => {
    return {
        weather: store.weather.weather   
    };          
})

export default class App extends React.Component {   
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.dispatch( fetchWeather({
            city: 'Boston',
            state: 'MA'
        }));  
    }
    render(){

        const {weather} = this.props;

        return (
           <div> 
               <h1> Weather Check </h1>
                  <Weather weather={weather} />
                 <LocationForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And in Weather.js ( commented over the problem area )

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Weather extends React.Component {
    render(){ 

        //Problem here
        if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.props.weather).length === 0){
            return(<div></div>)
        }

        return (
            <div> 
               <h3> { this.props.weather.current_observation.display_location.full} </h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What i always receive is:

[image]

I have tried almost all options from the stackoverflow posts mentioning the Object.getOwnPropertyNames returning undefined or null error, but still no luck. Any pointers wud be of great help !

Advanced cheers!

Comment: Why are you using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`? Why not just... `if (this.props.weather) { .. } ` ?

Comment: azium, infact i had tried the one which u told,  still, it doesnt go through. Like i mentioned in the post, i tried a dozen ways to see if the same is fetched, Using if( this.props.fetched), moving the class component, to a container component, and then using props as a parameter, using a constructor() and inside setting this.props.weather = {} initially..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` after @azium's suggestion, you can do the following to prevent the error and ensure you always pass a valid object:

```
 @connect( (store) => {
  return {
     weather: store.weather.weather || {}
  };          
})
```

Comment: Rami enbashi, thanks! that did the trick of getting rid of errors. Thank you both of you for the quick response, i was stuck for sometime. Though i am not out of woods, the next state is still not showing the data i need, so digging, atleast one step taken, !!! cheers both ! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

And to complete the answer, i was not getting the value on screen because of a typo in the reducer,

```
case "FETCH_WEATHER_FULLFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                weather: action.payload
            }
        }
```

and the action was

```
.then((response) => {           
           dispatch({
               type: "FETCH_WEATHER_FULLFILLED", 
               weather: response.data 
           })
```

which was a typo, actually, what i should have typed was action.weather instead of action.payload

```
case "FETCH_WEATHER_FULLFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                weather: action.weather
            }
        }
```